# Disable smooth scrolling in Preview in Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, scrolling, preview

Smooth scrolling in Lion's Preview application sucks. Pressing the Page-Down key too quickly leaves you waiting for Preview to catch up to your position.

The only way I can find to turn this off is to switch from "Continuous Scroll" to "Single Page" view, but I don't want to view pages like that. The system prefs for "General/Smooth Scrolling" do nothing.

Is there any way to get my jerky scrolling back (apart from switching to Adobe Reader)?

Comment: You can always file a bug against Preview/OS X Lion with Apple. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple and got a notice that this is a known issue and hopefully will get fixed.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/339305/how-do-i-disable-animations-in-preview-in-lion

Answer (score 5):

The new menu items *Go - Previous Item* (⌥↑) and *Go - Next Item* (⌥↓) aren't animated. They seem to behave like ⇞ and ⇟, but without scrolling documents that don't fit the window vertically. And they always align the top of the document to the top of the window in the *Continuous Scroll* mode.

They don't have that equally annoying page-slide animation in the *Single Page* or *Two Pages* modes either.

Comment: As far as I remember, that used to be left-arrow and right-arrow in PDFs (in the old Preview). Too bad that they made it stick to the top of the page and don't allow an arbitrary position.

Comment: In 10.6 either the horizontal or vertical arrow keys can be used, as long as there's no scroll bar on that axis.