# How do I disable animations in Preview in Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, preview, animation

For example, open up a pdf and set view to two pages and hit arrow key up/down. Is there a way to get rid of the animation? Preview feels really snappy and fast, and to have animations like that just spoils all the fun. Might seem like a proper first world problem, especially if you're just a casual user of pdfs. But I frequently have 10+ pdfs open for referencing purposes (that is, a lot of flicking back and forth), and the animation just drives me nuts.

Comment: You're not alone in this. There's a thread at http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1205891 about the same thing. Worth keeping an eye on both and updating with the answer

Comment: I have no answer yet.  I only just encountered the Preview animation, somehow -- I normally use continuous scroll, but for this ("A Lesser Photographer", which has been mentioned a lot on the net recently) I wanted to see whole pages at a time.  And, man -- this is really annoying, even on a 2011 MBP.  Lion, Lion, why do you hate me so?

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21525/disabling-previews-sliding-animation ?

Answer (score 6):

On 10.7, option-up (Go > Previous Item) and option-down (Go > Next Item) aren't animated. Unlike page up and page down, they go to the next page even when the current page has a vertical scrollbar and isn't scrolled to the bottom.

---

The animations appear to have been removed on 10.8. There's however several visual glitches when changing pages at least on my installation:

- Images of other pages or graphic glitches are sometimes displayed for a split second
- The right page or both pages turn transparent for a split second when changing pages in full screen
- The bottom corners of windows turn to squares after changing pages by pressing the arrow keys

Can anyone reproduce the bugs? Is the lack of animations another bug or specific to my setup?

Comment: I never noticed those. I wonder if you could remap the arrow keys to Next and Previous Item instead...

Comment: @c00kiemonster You could in the Keyboard preference pane. But it would conflict with the functions `↑` and `↓` have in text fields.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either of those bugs in 10.8, this is a fresh install and there are no animations.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent the very annoying page slide transition animations in Preview is to use the mouse wheel, not very precise, but is a way.

The other, which I prefer, is to open the Thumbnails side panel, select a page and then when you press arrows up/down the effect is not used. If you use the page up/down keys though the effect is used.

Not much, but it's something.